# Error de Consumo de Mensajes JMS. Conexiones MQ en Weblogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic, websphere-mq

Buen día a todos, tengo la siguiente situación: resulta que tengo que dar mantenimiento a un proyecto, para esto utilizo un nuevo dominio en **Weblogic Server**, en el cual realizo distintas configuraciones de servidores ajenos **`MQ`**. Cabe mencionar que estas configuraciones y ¨***servidores ajenos MQ*** son las mismas que se utilizan en la versión anterior del proyecto que me encuentro modificando.

He desplegado mis componentes de forma exitosa, los cuales escuchan mensajes tipo MQ, sin embargo, cuando inyecto un mensaje en la `queue` de entrada de cualquier componente, este no se consume, se queda encolado.

Lo curioso es que no me muestra absolutamente nada, ni siquiera un error, simplemente los mensajes no son consumidos. Es importante mencionar que el dominio en el cual se desarrollo el proyecto, todo funciona a la perfección, pero en el nuevo no.

Creímos que era la versión de **Weblogic** pero probamos instalando la misma, en si se puede decir que hemos hecho una copia del dominio en el que funciona todo bien, pero esto no ha resultado.

La verdad ya llevamos rato varados en esta situación, les agradecería su ayuda.

P.D: Si no me he explicado bien, por favor hacérmelo saber.

Comment: Tal vez si cambiaron el servidor que consume, sea necesario que el servidor en donde se encuentran las MQ, le proporcione permisos al primero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En efecto como lo menciono @Darth Vader, no se habían dado los permisos, bueno en realidad se dieron pero nunca se reinicio el servidor por lo cual no los estaba tomando en cuenta. En conclusión: dar permisos y reiniciar el servidor.